# Gmail API Oauth: how to get background notification if invalid grant?

Tags: oauth-2.0, notifications, google-oauth, gmail-api

Gmail API oauth is used on background to send email. But after running for a while, get "Invalid Grant" error. Will refresh token expire? No password changes for the Gmail account.

How to send notification to admin in case of "invalid grant" so that Oauth re-authorization can be done in timely manner?  Obviously sending notification by Gmail will not work. On Gmail server side, any notification mechanism? e.g., Gmail server sends a notification email to the oauth gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for invalid grant error these days is the refresh token expring for apps currently in testing.

[expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

The solution is to set your app to production

[image]

due to the fact that the gmail scopes are involved you may also have to verify the app but im not sure i have had conflicting reports.

Answer (score 0):

***Will refresh token expire?***
If you have not implemented refresh token, you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#exchange_the_authorization_code_for_an_access_token). Refresh tokens expire too, there is currently a limit of 50 refresh tokens per Google Account per OAuth 2.0 client ID. If the limit is reached, creating a new refresh token automatically invalidates the oldest refresh token without warning. Most normal users won't exceed this limit but a developer's account used to test an implementation might.

***How to send notification to admin in case of "invalid grant" so that Oauth re-authorization can be done in a timely manner?***
At the moment there is no option through Google API’s side to send these kind of notifications. The workaround would be to implement a custom exception in your coding to send an email when the exception occurs.

There are many reasons why users receive the "invalid_grant" error.

- The user has revoked your app's access.
- The refresh token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.
- The user belongs to a Google Cloud Platform organization that has session control policies in effect.
- A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen
  configured for an external user type and a publishing status of
  "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

Comment: Welcome to stack:  if you are going to copy 90% of your answer directly out of the documentation its best to leave a link to that documentation in the event its changed in the future [expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)   This link can also be found in my answer.  Google in my experience updates their docs often. [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: In case of "Invalid grant", could not send notification by email. Is there another way except SMS(text messaging)? thanks.

Comment: @eastwater Unfortunately, through Google there is no notification to track "invalid_grant" errors. The best would be to determine why users are getting the error to give a solution.